# WxPython creating NewEvent in loop leads to GUI slow down

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have  a thread running which monitors the state of things, and posts an event to refresh the Gui with a max rate of 0.1s. However, I noticed after several hours that the Gui became sluggish and would eventually freeze.

```
class Hello(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        self.refreshEvent, EVT_REFRESH_GUI = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
        self.Bind(EVT_REFRESH_GUI, self.__RefreshGui)

    def MyThread(self):

        while(True):
            # Do stuff
            self.var = self.GetVar()

            # Post refresh event.
            refreshEvent = self.refreshEvent()
            wx.PostEvent(self, refreshEvent)
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def __RefreshGui(self, event):
        pass
```

I just realized that if I move `refreshEvent = self.refreshEvent()` outside the while loop everything seems much more responsive.

I haven't seen anything about creating new events causing lag. Is this a known and expected behavior? Is this specifically because of wxPython, or is this from wxWidgets?

```
class Hello(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        self.refreshEvent, EVT_REFRESH_GUI = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
        self.Bind(EVT_REFRESH_GUI, self.__RefreshGui)

    def MyThread(self):
        refreshEvent = self.refreshEvent()
        while(True):
            # Do stuff
            self.var = self.GetVar()

            # Post refresh event.
            wx.PostEvent(self, refreshEvent)
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def __RefreshGui(self, event):
        pass
```

EDIT:

To address some of the current comments and answers, this is a simplified view of the real code to try and focus on what was causing my issue. Yes, there is a real thread in the code. We can try to move towards a `wxTimer` approach for the future, and I appreciate the feedback because I was wondering how to best go about this. The reason we are using `PostEvent` is because we needed it to be thread safe. Previously we were running into segfault issues from different threads calling the same things. There is a significant amount of legacy code, and this seemed like a good approach at the time.

The question was really wondering if there was an inherent slowdown with the number of custom events created and posted. Is the approach of creating events and posting events many, many times expected to lead to a slowdown?

Comment: I am not a Python programmer but that does not look like a thread to me and why dont you use a `wxTimer` which you can put in the constructor of your `Hello` class.

Comment: In the real case `MyThread` is a real thread, I was just trying to simplify the code to what was causing the issue. Perhaps that was a mistake. The reason I'm not using `wxTimer` is because it needed to be thread safe for legacy code reasons. Things can be called from other threads and were causing segfaults. Yes, maybe we could migrate to this, but the question was trying to see if there was something inherently wrong with trying to create and using 'PostEvent' in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you call a class method `MyThread` does not automatically make it a Thread. But in some way you are already on the right track.

You will want to check out the topic [LongRunningTasks on the wxPython wiki](https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks), especially the section **Easiest Implementation *Ever* :)** at the bottom of the page.

Your GUI freezes because you are eating up all resources by `sleep`ing in an endless `while` loop. This guarantees that wxPython will not be able to react to any Events any more (also the one you created yourself).

My advice: First, get rid of your custom event. You do not need that here.

You essentially have two options:

1. Moving the `sleep` into a separate thread and communicate with the main GUI thread in thread-safe ways (e. g. `wx.CallBack`). This is described very well in the wiki link.
2. If you just need some code which is run every 100 ms, use `wx.Timer` (see the wxPython demo for an example). However, you have to make sure, that your work can be done in well than below 100 ms, otherwise events will pile up. If this is an concern, use Method 1 instead.

Comment: In the real case `MyThread` is indeed a real thread, not just called a thread. In the real case we aren't using sleep in this exact manner, but from what I can tell sleep does release the python GIL. The sluggishness happens after several hours and the freeze after ~8hours. We are doing a 'PostEvent' because we needed a thread safe manner of calling our function (some legacy code issues, but yes we could try moving to a `wx.Timer`). I guess I wasn't clear enough, but what I was wondering was if creating and posting an event in an infinite loop was expected to lead to an eventual freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Without repeating what others have said, although I agree, here's a simple `wx.timer` example:

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title,size=(350, 225))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Text = wx.StaticText(panel,-1,"Tick")
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onTimer, self.timer)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.Text, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.timer.Start(2000) # fire every 2 seconds
        self.Show()

    def onTimer(self, evt):
        if self.Text.GetLabel() == "Tick":
            self.Text.SetLabel("Tock")
        else:
            self.Text.SetLabel("Tick")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    MyFrame(None,"Tick Tock timer")
    app.MainLoop()
```